Residue fields commute with quotients?
Is the following statement true? And if so, is my proof correct?
Let $A$ be a ring and $q \subseteq p \subseteq A$ prime ideals. There exists a (unique) isomorphism
$$
A_p/pA_p \xrightarrow{\cong} (A/q)_p/p(A/q)_p
$$
The right term is well-defined since $p \subseteq A/q$ is again a prime ideal.
Proof.
Consider the following diagram:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>>> A/q @>>> (A/q)_p @>>> (A/q)_p/p(A/q)_p \\
@VVV @V\exists !V(1)V @V\exists !V(2)V @V\exists !V(3)V \\
A_p @>>> A_p/pA_p @>=>> A_p/pA_p @>=>> A_p/pA_p
\end{CD}
$$
The map (1) is induced by the universal property of quotients, (2) is induced by the universal property of localization, and (3) is again induced by the universal property of quotients.
The map (2) is given by
$$
\frac{[a]}{[s]} \mapsto [\frac{s}{1}]^{-1} \cdot [\frac{a}{1}] = [\frac{a}{s}]
$$
which is surjective and the kernel is precisely $p(A/q)_p$.

Yes, this is correct, the proof is fine too. If you want a bit quicker proof, you can start with $A/p \cong (A/q)/(p/q)$ by the third isomorphism theorem, then from the fact that localization is exact, conclude that $A_p/p_p \cong (A/q)_p/(p/q)_p$.
